# Remove files in range with cmd

Tags: bash, cmd

I have files named `0000.jpg 0001.jpg 00002.jpg`... and so on. I want to delete some files in a range. What is the equivalent bash command for windows cmd?

```
rm *{0010..0060}.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A counting loop might do. In a cmd window enter

```
for /l %A in (10,1,60) do @Echo del "*00%A.jpg"
```

If output seems ok remove the `echo` in front of the `del`
In a batch-file you have to double the `%-signs`

**Edit** Here a Powershell way

```
10..60 | % { gci  $_.ToString("*0000\.jpg")|rm -whatif }
```

If output seems ok, remove the -whatif

Answer (score 0):

del is the equivalent, but I don't think you can use { } with it.
del /? will give you the help.
Sorry I can't help more, I'm not a Windows PC for now.